# Custom authentication with django?

Tags: django, authentication

Because I didn't want to use Django's in-build authentication system (maybe I should do, please tell me if this is the case), I created a simple little auth class:

```
import random
import hashlib
from myapp import models

class CustomerAuth:
    key = 'customer'

    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def attempt(self, email_address, password):
        password_hash = hashlib.sha1(password).hexdigest()
        try:
            return models.Customer.objects.get(
                email_address=email_address,
                password_hash=password_hash)
        except models.Customer.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def login(self, customer):
        self.session[self.key] = customer

    def logout(self):
        if self.session.has_key(self.key):
            self.session[self.key] = None

    def is_logged_in(self):
        return self.session.has_key(self.key)
            and self.session[self.key] != None

    def get_active(self):
        if self.is_logged_in():
            return self.session[self.key]
        else:
            raise Exception('No user is logged in.')

    def redirect_to_login(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

    def redirect_from_login(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/')
```

The problem is, that when I want to use it to stop unauthorized access, I have to use this code snippet in every single view method:

```
def example(req):
    auth = CustomerAuth(req.session)
    if not auth.is_logged_in():
        return auth.redirect_to_login()
```

As you can imagine, this yields fairly ugly and repetitive code. What is a better way of doing this? Should I be using Django's auth framework?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, yes you should use Django's authentication framework, and build your own [custom auth backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend).

Secondly, however you do it, you'll need to have something in the views that you want to restrict access to. The best way to do that is via a decorator on the view. Again, Django's built-in framework gives you access to the [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks - just implemented it now. It's actually very easy to do surprisingly. Plus, I don't need to use the username attribute even through it's "required" (since I want to do authentication with email addresses).